# How to Detect plants and get the shape of them using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection, object-recognition

Now, I'm trying to detect the growth of plants by comparing pictures of plants.
The camera on a flower pot will take the picture of the plant every hour. I want to my device get heights of each picture and compare them relatively using openCV. But I got some trouble with detecting of plants.
How can detects them and get shape using openCV?

-----------------------[Details]---------------

You can assume that there are one flower pot and one camera.

The positions of them is fixed.

So we can calculate relative difference of a flower's height from two 
picture.

Comment: is the camera stationary fixed? you should add some sample images.

Comment: @Micka I added some details. Thanks

Comment: can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

first :

- you can detect the plant by its color `inRange(high,low)`.

second :

- markers works better ( more accuracy) you need two markers at most for height(since your positions are fixed you can use one just for the top). just draw two circles on a paper and stick it on your plant.